# Linking or copying files

Tags: ubuntu

I'm working with a remote device (RasberryPi B running Debian Wheezy). The device connects to a CIFS share. I'm going to have many of these devices all connecting to the same CIFS share.

The file structure for the share is

```
-DEVICE 1
--MEDIA
---IMAGE01
-DEVICE 2
--MEDIA
---IMAGE01
```

I want to also be able to have

```
-SHARED
--MEDIA
---IMAGE10
```

I need that file (`IMAGE10`) to appear in the `MEDIA` folder of the device share, as the device can only mount one CIFS share. I've tried soft linking the file, but the application on the device cannot see the file. I'm not sure where that is an issue with the symlink being outside of the share?

Hard linking works, but obviously if I change the file in the `SHARED` drive, it doesn't change the file.

What is the best way to sync the file? The NAS is running Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: You will need CIFS VFS kernel module version 1.40 or later for the cifs mount to recognize symbolic links.

Comment: Are you setting up the share so that all of the directories are contained within it, or are these two separate shares? If it's the latter, could you make another share that combines the two shares (e.g. `/opt/share` -> {`shared`, `devices/` -> {`device1`, `device2`}}? Also, if you're sharing between two Linux machines, have you thought about using NFS instead of CIFS?

Comment: I cannot change the protocol or anything used by the RapsberryPi unfortunately. So I'm stuck using SMB1.0. At the moment these are separate shares because, once again, that's how they are access by the Pi. They could access the same share with different usernames/passwords if that makes any difference?